# Starting a Song from Spotify Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify

Is there anyway to start a Spotify Track from its URI ?

I've tried the following approaches but none of them work.  When Spotify opens, it always lands in the Playlists page, instead of the track's player.

```
String spotifyTrackURI = "spotify:track:1cC9YJ8sQjC0T5H1fXMUT2";
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui");

// I've tried with Intent#putExtra()..
launchIntent.putExtra( SearchManager.QUERY, spotifyTrackURI );
// or with setData
launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse(spotifyTrackURI))

context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer on the #spotify channel on Freenode (irc).  Thanks everyone!

I'm putting it here for other people to know about:

```
// right click on a track in Spotify to get the URI, or use the Web API.
String uri = "spotify:track:<spotify uri>"; 
Intent launcher = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri) );
startActivity(launcher);
```

Comment: This no longer works  - the spotify app opens, but music is not played automatically. Anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

First one is for old Spotify version.
For new versions you can use the second.

In this way it will first try with old version, if it fails with an exception it try with the second one :)

```
try {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui", "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.Launcher"));
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, artistName + " " + trackName );
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e ) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui", "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.activity.MainActivity"));
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, artistName + " " + trackName );
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, where in this code is the URI being passed?

Comment: I don't think that spotify will use uri in his search intent. In my example he's using a search with trackname and artistname.

Comment: OK, I understand this now, unfortunately I'm not trying to do a search, I already have the URI of the songs I want to play on the app.  I'm wondering, how did you find out that Spotify supports this Search Intent type.  Is there anyway to know which Intent types does Spotify (or any Android app for that matter) support?

Comment: Most of good apps support this kind of intent :) you have only to find the package and class to call :P

Answer (score 0):

If you get playlist for Artist on Spotify app. You need to start following intent. You do not need to package name or activity of Spotify.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("spotify:artist:" + "ARTIST SPOTIFY LINK"));
                startActivity(intent);
```