# Starting Spotify App From Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify

I'm attempting to initialize a Spotify search exactly like what is mentioned here: [Starting a Song from Spotify Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698428/starting-a-song-from-spotify-intent)

However, the example code always gives me an Activity Not Found Exception.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to overcome this?

Thanks!

Here is my current code for reference:

```
try {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui", "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.Launcher"));
                    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, trackName );
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e ) {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui", "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.activity.MainActivity"));
                    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, trackName );
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Comment: Have you installed Spotify on the phone?

Comment: Yes, I installed it recently, before running the code!

Comment: `intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.music", "com.spotify.music.MainActivity"));`

This fixed it, I was using an older one.

Comment: On that note... is it possible to do a Spotify search and then Play the top result from another app? All my current call does is activate a spotify search, but I'd prefer to start playing the best result

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.music", "com.spotify.music.MainActivity"));
```

This fixed it, the package I was using was for an older Spotify app.